# select columns into rows grouped by columns values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table of logins that looks like this:

logins table

```
Emp_ID    Created                |  Action
1       20/01/2016 10:44:42 AM      login
1       20/01/2016 4:45:49 PM       logout
1       20/01/2016 6:30:13 PM       logout
1       21/01/2016 8:46:28 AM       login
1       21/01/2016 9:46:42 AM       login
1       21/01/2016 1:46:46 PM       logout
1       22/01/2016 8:49:21 AM       login
1       22/01/2016 1:49:27 PM       logout
1       22/01/2016 2:29:53 PM       login
1       22/01/2016 2:30:13 PM       logout
3       22/01/2016 2:42:06 PM       login
1       22/01/2016 9:57:22 PM       login
1       22/01/2016 10:22:23 PM      logout
1       23/01/2016 8:01:47 AM       login
1       23/01/2016 9:01:58 AM       logout
3       23/01/2016 8:02:06 AM       login
3       23/01/2016 9:02:28 AM       logout
```

The employees table

```
| ID | Fname | Lname |
|----|-------|-------|
|  1 | James | Brown |
|  2 |  Mark |  Bond |
|  3 |  Kemi |   Ojo |
```

The result I got

```
|    created |    login |   logout |    Employee | Emp_ID |
|------------|----------|----------|-------------|--------|
| 2016-01-20 | 10:44:42 | 18:30:13 | James Brown |      1 |
| 2016-01-21 | 08:46:28 | 13:46:46 | James Brown |      1 |
| 2016-01-22 | 08:49:21 | 22:22:23 | James Brown |      1 |
| 2016-01-22 | 14:42:06 | 22:22:23 |    Kemi Ojo |      3 |
| 2016-01-23 | 08:01:47 | 09:02:28 | James Brown |      1 |
| 2016-01-23 | 08:02:06 | 09:02:28 |    Kemi Ojo |      3 |
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT
    CAST(LI.created AS DATE) AS created,
    MIN(CAST(LI.created AS TIME)) AS login,
    MAX(CAST(LO.created AS TIME)) AS logout,
    e.fname+' '+e.lname Employee, li.Emp_ID

FROM
    Logins LI
LEFT OUTER JOIN Logins LO ON
    LO.action = 'logout' AND
    CAST(LO.created AS DATE) = CAST(LI.created AS DATE)
    JOIN dbo.Employees AS E ON E.ID = li.Emp_ID

WHERE
    LI.action = 'login'
GROUP BY
    CAST(LI.created AS DATE), E.fname + ' ' + E.lname, li.Emp_ID
```

But the result is not correct.

1. Notice that the last two result for different users are the same. for example `09:02:28` appears twice instead of `9:01:58`
2. Also I have issues with a login without a logout for emp_id = 3. this happens when the app shuts down unexpectedly.

3 how can i place a 00:00:00 in the case when there is no logout
4. Or what would be your suggestion of what to do in this case?

I need to select a result set that looks like this:

```
|    created |    login |   logout |    Employee | Emp_ID |
|------------|----------|----------|-------------|--------|
| 2016-01-20 | 10:44:42 | 18:30:13 | James Brown |      1 |
| 2016-01-21 | 08:46:28 | 13:46:46 | James Brown |      1 |
| 2016-01-22 | 08:49:21 | 22:22:23 | James Brown |      1 |
| 2016-01-22 | 14:42:06 | 00:00:00 |    Kemi Ojo |      3 |
| 2016-01-23 | 08:01:47 | 09:01:58 | James Brown |      1 |
| 2016-01-23 | 08:02:06 | 09:02:28 |    Kemi Ojo |      3 |
```

[**SQL fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/465f0/2)

Comment: This is a very good question: Clear, sample data, your own attempt, wrong output, expected output. Thx for this, +1 from my side!

Comment: Yeah. This question's link should be given in `how to ask question` page specifically for SQL questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, cudos for a prefect question. Table structure, fiddle demo and expected output helps a lot.

Now I tried this and it is working in fiddle. Please recheck and let me know.

```
select t_login.emp_id,t_login.dt_created as created,t_login.login,
case when t_logout.logout is null 
    then cast('00:00:00' as time)
else t_logout.logout end as logout,
e.fname+' '+e.lname Employee
from 
    (select emp_id,CAST(created AS DATE) AS dt_created,
    MIN(CAST(created AS TIME)) as login
    from logins
    where action='login'
    group by emp_id,CAST(created AS DATE)) t_login
left join
    (select emp_id,CAST(created AS DATE) AS dt_created,
    max(CAST(created AS TIME)) as logout
    from logins
    where action='logout'
    group by emp_id,CAST(created AS DATE)) t_logout
        on t_login.emp_id=t_logout.emp_id
        and t_login.dt_created=t_logout.dt_created
inner join 
    employees e
        on e.id=t_login.emp_id
```

PS: This will not take care of cases where there is no login on a particular day and only a logout. If you want that, then use a `full outer join` and use same `case` statement as I used in outer `select` clause.

**See fiddle demo here**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/465f0/34

Ouput

```
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| emp_id  |  created    |      login        |      logout       |  Employee   |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
|      1  | 2016-01-20  | 10:44:42.0000000  | 18:30:13.0000000  | James Brown |
|      1  | 2016-01-21  | 08:46:28.0000000  | 13:46:46.0000000  | James Brown |
|      1  | 2016-01-22  | 08:49:21.0000000  | 22:22:23.0000000  | James Brown |
|      3  | 2016-01-22  | 14:42:06.0000000  | 00:00:00.0000000  | Kemi Ojo    |
|      1  | 2016-01-23  | 08:01:47.0000000  | 09:01:58.0000000  | James Brown |
|      3  | 2016-01-23  | 08:02:06.0000000  | 09:02:28.0000000  | Kemi Ojo    |
+---------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Good solution, It is technically the same approach as mine, the difference is, that you use nested sub-selects while I packed them in CTEs. +1 from my side

Comment: I have suggested an edit to get rid of the CASE WHEN in the outer SELECT. :)

Comment: Hi @DavidBachmannJeppesen - Appreciate your effort in suggesting edit. The `case` statement works across all RDBMS. However I am not sure about `isnull`. Please dont mind. Thanks for it anyways. Have a good day :)

Comment: Anytime! The isnull() is the correct function on SQL Server. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is my suggestion (be aware of culture specific date literals. I had to set a language to get a correct date conversion):

```
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;

DECLARE @logins TABLE(Emp_ID INT,Created DATETIME, Action VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @logins VALUES
 (1,'20/01/2016 10:44:42 AM','login')
,(1,'20/01/2016 4:45:49 PM','logout')
,(1,'20/01/2016 6:30:13 PM','logout')
,(1,'21/01/2016 8:46:28 AM','login')
,(1,'21/01/2016 9:46:42 AM','login')
,(1,'21/01/2016 1:46:46 PM','logout')
,(1,'22/01/2016 8:49:21 AM','login')
,(1,'22/01/2016 1:49:27 PM','logout')
,(1,'22/01/2016 2:29:53 PM','login')
,(1,'22/01/2016 2:30:13 PM','logout')
,(3,'22/01/2016 2:42:06 PM','login')
,(1,'22/01/2016 9:57:22 PM','login')
,(1,'22/01/2016 10:22:23 PM','logout')
,(1,'23/01/2016 8:01:47 AM','login')
,(1,'23/01/2016 9:01:58 AM','logout')
,(3,'23/01/2016 8:02:06 AM','login')
,(3,'23/01/2016 9:02:28 AM','logout');

DECLARE @employees TABLE(ID INT,Fname VARCHAR(100),Lname VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @employees VALUES
 (1,'James','Brown')
,(2,'Mark','Bond')
,(3,'Kemi','Ojo'); 

WITH Logins AS
(
    SELECT
         MIN(PureDate) AS Created
        ,MIN(CAST(l.Created AS TIME)) AS LoginTime
        ,l.Emp_ID
    FROM @logins AS l
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(l.Created AS DATE) PureDate) AS Created 
    WHERE l.Action ='login'
    GROUP BY l.Emp_ID,PureDate  
)
,Logouts AS
(
    SELECT
         MAX(PureDate) AS Created
        ,MAX(CAST(l.Created AS TIME)) AS LogoutTime
        ,l.Emp_ID
    FROM @logins AS l
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(l.Created AS DATE) PureDate) AS Created 
    WHERE l.Action ='logout'
    GROUP BY l.Emp_ID,PureDate  
)
SELECT Logins.Created
      ,Logins.LoginTime 
      ,ISNULL(Logouts.LogoutTime,'00:00:00')
      ,e.Lname 
      ,e.ID 
FROM Logins
INNER JOIN @employees AS e ON e.ID = Logins.Emp_ID
LEFT JOIN Logouts ON Logins.Emp_ID = Logouts.Emp_ID 
                 AND Logins.Created = Logouts.Created 
ORDER BY Created,LoginTime
```

The result

```
2016-01-20  10:44:42    18:30:13    Brown   1
2016-01-21  08:46:28    13:46:46    Brown   1
2016-01-22  08:49:21    22:22:23    Brown   1
2016-01-22  14:42:06    00:00:00    Ojo     3
2016-01-23  08:01:47    09:01:58    Brown   1
2016-01-23  08:02:06    09:02:28    Ojo     3
```

Comment: I could test you code in the fiddle, but had to take time to make it work in code, which i haven't got

Comment: @Smith To test this is very simple: Just paste the whole lot into an empty query window and execute. This works with declared table variables (they start with a `@`) therefore you don't need any existing structures to test it... To use it needs nothing more than to change the table variables to the actual tables one want to read from.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a JOIN between the LO table and the LI table:

```
AND LO.Emp_ID = LI.Emp_ID
```

I think you can do this without using a self-join and using CASE WHEN instead, which I think would be prettier, but try this addition.

EDIT from comment:
Just replace:
    MAX(CAST(LO.Created AS Time))
...with:
    MAX(CAST(isnull(LO.Created, '00:00:00') AS Time))

Comment: this works but does not take care of the logins in a date without logout for that day